# What's the correct way to capture the return code of an alert sheet for OS X 10.9+?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

According to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAlert_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAlert/beginSheetModalForWindow:completionHandler:), it appears that the only non-deprecated method for displaying an alert sheet is `beginSheetModalForWindow:completionHandler:`, where `completionHandler` block takes an argument of `NSModalResponse`-type.  `NSModalResponse` is an enum with only [3 possible values](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSModalResponse): `NSModalResponseStop`, `NSModalResponseAbort` and `NSModalResponseContinue`. So how do I know which button on an alert sheet was clicked by the user?

Comment: All 3 of the `NSModalResponse` values in the enum are negative. Try logging the value passed to the completion handler, maybe it will pass the clicked button index instead if applicable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result code is not really an enum in the sense that it's not restricted to just the values of the `NSModalResponse` type. The enum is only used to define *some* of the possible values.

See the documentation for the [`-addButtonWithTitle:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAlert_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002032-BCIGGDHD) method of `NSAlert`, for example, which explains the response codes generated from the added button: `NSAlertFirstButtonReturn` for the first, `NSAlertSecondButtonReturn` for the second, `NSAlertThirdButtonReturn` for the third, and `NSAlertThirdButtonReturn` + *n* for subsequent buttons.

See also the documentation for the [`-runModal`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAlert_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002032-BCICIIBG) method:

> If you use [`alertWithMessageText:defaultButton:alternateButton:otherButton:informativeTextWithFormat:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAlert_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSAlert/alertWithMessageText:defaultButton:alternateButton:otherButton:informativeTextWithFormat:) to create an alert, the following constants are used to identify the button used to dismiss the alert: [`NSAlertDefaultReturn`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSPanel_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSAlertDefaultReturn), [`NSAlertAlternateReturn`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSPanel_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSAlertAlternateReturn), and [`NSAlertOtherReturn`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSPanel_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSAlertOtherReturn). Otherwise, the constants used are the ones described in [“Button Return Values.”](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAlert_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Button_Return_Values)

That's the same rule that applies for the response code passed to the completion handler you supply to `-beginSheetModalForWindow:completionHandler:`.